# Laravel error after git clone: Cannot declare class App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Bean\BeanForm, because the name is already in use

Tags: laravel, git

I am developing a site with laravel 9.

I created the site on my desktop and on my laptop, made some changes on the desktop and wanted to get the changes from the desktop to the laptop.

I never used Git before so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

I created the repository on github, from my desktop with Visual Studio.

I cloned the repository on my laptop.

I copied the folders and files that are in gitignore manually from the previous folder of the same project that I had on my laptop:
/node_modules
/public/storage
/vendor
.env

Trying to run the site I get this error:
Cannot declare class App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Bean\BeanForm, because the name is already in use

I tried:
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

nothing helps.

I get the error with every view I'm trying to run.
It all runs perfectly on the computer I created the git repository from.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do not copy paste stuff like that, just re download `npm install` and `composer install` (you can copy `.env` and `public/storage`). Go to that file `App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Bean\BeanForm` and see if you have it duplicated or there is anything wrong or weird with the contents of the file. I recommend you to learn GIT as nowadays is a must and it is very easy to use (basic stuff), it is vital if you are a dev or going to be one. This is an AWESOME page that teaches you how to use GIT in an interactive way: https://learngitbranching.js.org/

Comment: Thank you. There is nothing strange in the file. If I'll do npm install and composer install there's a chance I won't have the same packages versions on both computers, right?

Comment: Not if you are sharing/using the same `composer.lock` and `package-lock.json`. Those 2 files LOCK the versions and constraits of everything, so they are always the same no matter what. If you are not sharing and syncing those files with GIT, you could have different versions of the pacakges installed

Comment: ok, npm install and composer install didn't help either. I'm going to redo it all and see if it works. Will update here when I'm done

Comment: Ok, redid it all, cloned the repository, npm install, composer install, copied .env, still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok, I found it, for some reason there was a duplicate file in 2 different folders. The strange thing is, this duplication does not exist on my desktop so I don't understand where did it come from.